# session not store Information from $_POST into session php

Tags: php, html

Why can not the post method can save data into session php
Here is my script what is wrong file1 call set.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>the form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="view.php" method="post" name="testform">
<input name="name" type="text"><br>
<input name="send" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

view.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION ['session_name'] = $_POST ['name'] ;
if (isset ($_SESSION ['session_name'])){
echo $_SESSION ['session_name'] ;
}
else {
echo ('no name');
}
?>
```

If I refresh the page name is not saved why?

Comment: not sure if that's it but can you remove those spaces $_POST['name'] and also here $_SESSION['session_name']

Comment: @user1780343 Include `<?php session_start(); ?>` on every page where you want to use session variables.

Comment: because $_POST['name'] variable not set when you refresh page. you should submit form instead of refresh page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an if statement to check if `$_POST['name']` is set otherwise you will just keep re writing on each load.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST ['name'])){
        $_SESSION ['session_name'] = $_POST ['name'];
    }

    if (isset ($_SESSION ['session_name'])){
        echo $_SESSION ['session_name'] ;
    }
    else {
        echo ('no name');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Oh that was me! That's suppose to be a upvote! My bad! :O Edit your post with something nonsensical and I can fix. Vote is locked.

Answer (score -1):

`$_POST['name']` not `$_POST ['name']` and so on for the rest of the tags.

Comment: i fix this $_SESSION ['session_name'] = $_POST['name'] ;

Comment: Look at smistry's answer. Checking if there is actually a `$_POST` is important.